# change Authorization path in WSO2 API

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

the applications have to use the default authorization path "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token" to get access token.
However I need to change this URL to "http://localhost:8280/token"

How can I change the Authorization path in WSO2 API-Manager??

Comment: We cannot change this within the product.
I believe you need to have an Nginx proxy to rewrite the URL. Or else you might be able to use APIM GW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as follows.

1. Create a file called _token.xml in APIM_HOME/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api.
2. Add the content below to the _token.xml file.

```xml
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="_WSO2AMTokenAPI_" context="/token">
    <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/*" faultSequence="_token_fault_">
        <inSequence>
            
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                     <http uri-template="https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token">
                        <timeout>
                            <duration>60000</duration>
                            <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                        </timeout>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </resource>
    <handlers>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerCacheExtensionHandler"/>
        <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.common.SynapsePropertiesHandler"/>
    </handlers>
</api>
```

3. Add the following configuration to the deployment.toml file repository/conf folder.

> [apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway.skip_list]
> apis = ["_token.xml"]

**Note:** Add this configuration value after the config value [apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway].

4. Start/Restart the server

Comment: What Can I do for Revoke and Refresh ??

Comment: You can find a similar definition for revoke here - https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/blob/v3.2.0/modules/distribution/product/src/main/conf/synapse-configs/default/api/_RevokeAPI_.xml

Comment: Other definitions can be found here - https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/tree/v3.2.0/modules/distribution/product/src/main/conf/synapse-configs/default/api

Comment: You can change the http uri-template to localhost:9443 as above.